# How to write a LIKE Statement in PHP Query?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, jsonexception

I'm creating an app that can retrieve the word by using the last letter of the inputted word. For example in my case on my existing database the sequence is Appl**e** > **E**lephan**t** > **T**rai**n** > **N**erv**e** > **E**ducatio**n** > **N**ewspape**r** > and I will input **R**ecipe because that's the last letter of the previous word. My problem is that I can't get the response. The app must give a word that start with the last letter of the previous word given. So in the tblcheckword the response must be either **E**mphasis or **E**mpire because in my query it is in rand() and LIMIT to 1

```
SELECT word FROM tblcheckword WHERE word LIKE '$word.%' ORDER BY rand() NOT IN (SELECT ig_word FROM tbltempgame) LIMIT 1;
```

I'm using the LIKE statement for getting the last letter of the inputted word. But again I still getting error.

[image: This is my error]

Here's my PHP File "checkplsv2.php"

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "check") or die ("Error ".mysqli_error($con));
$word = $_POST["word"];
$sql = "SELECT word FROM tblcheckword where word like '$word.%' order by rand() not in (select ig_word from tbltempgame) LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error in selecting ".mysqli_error($con));

$response = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($response, array("id"=>$row[0],"ig_word"=>$row[1],"meaning"=>$row[2]));
        $retrieve = $row[1];
    }
    echo json_encode(array("server_response" => $retrieve));
}else{
    echo "Retrieve failed";
}

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.keam.lastnato;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String id;
String word;
String ig_word;
InputStream is = null;
String result = null;
String line = null;
String data = "";
TextView disp;
String url = "http://192.168.22.16/checkplsv2.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText e_word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            word = e_word.getText().toString();
            select();
        }
    });
}

void select() {

    class readThis extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("word", word));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }


            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                ig_word = json_data.getString("server_response");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name: " +   
                ig_word,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TextView disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                disp.setText(ig_word);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was: " + result);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }

    }

    readThis hello = new readThis();
    hello.execute(new String[]{url});
    }
}
```

Here's my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:hint="Player's Turn"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:onClick="parseJSON"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:text="Select" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my tblcheckword and tbltempgame in WAMP phpmyadmin

Database Name = "check"

[image: Here's my tblcheckword and tbltempword in WAMP phpmyadmin]

Here's my logcat error.

```
09-04 19:23:52.051 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.051 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.051 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.051 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.061 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.071 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.071 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.071 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.081 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.091 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:23:52.091 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.keam.lastnato.MainActivity.access$super
09-04 19:24:01.960 11820-12003/com.example.keam.lastnato E/pass 1: connection success 
09-04 19:24:01.960 11820-12003/com.example.keam.lastnato E/pass 2: connection success 
09-04 19:24:01.960 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/Fail 3: org.json.JSONException: Value Retrieve of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-04 19:24:01.960 11820-11820/com.example.keam.lastnato E/log_tag: Failed data was: Retrieve failed
```

Comment: You sql query is obviously incorrect.

Comment: PHP Query is actually an old html parser library, it has nothing to do with sql (think jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is incorrect.

Try this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT `word` FROM `tblcheckword`WHERE `word` LIKE ".$word."% NOT IN(select ig_word from tbltempgame)  ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: This is incorrect as well. ORDER BY has to be put after WHERE condition...

Comment: I still got an error. Here's what it says.

E/log_tag: Failed data was: Error in selecting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% order by rand() not in (select ig_word from tbltempgame) LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Here's what it says. 

`E/log_tag: Failed data was: Error in selecting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'word' LIKE Recipe% NOT IN(select ig_word from tbltempgame) LIMIT 1' at line 1`

Sir @KinshukLahiri

Comment: Sorry, I haven't updated that order by as mentioned by @pedrounan. Please check now sir.

Comment: Here's the logcat Sir @KinshukLahiri

`E/Fail 3: org.json.JSONException: Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`


`E/log_tag: Failed data was: Error in selecting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% NOT IN(select ig_word from tbltempgame)  ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1' at line 1`

I still getting error Sir.